YouTube only loading one minute at a time
Using Firefox on Windows 11, YouTube will only load the first minute of a video at a time. It will play one minute and then buffer endlessly. If I change the url to include &t=60 and then reload, it will play another minute, and then I need to change the url to &t=120. The fact that's it's exactly one minute makes me suspect this is deliberate, but I don't know what's causing it. Bizarrely, the issue goes away if I log out or use another web browser than Firefox.

Same problem for all my devices via web browser, but all normal via YouTube application.

I have the same issue. It only happens on Firefox when signed in. You can watch the video for 1 minute and then it stops loading.
You can use yt-dlp via PowerShell to download videos.
or
You can download a user agent switcher for your browser on the Mozilla extension store.
